# The animated text not working as the Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have coded a function to animate a texts by manipulating the ID and set animation delay to change the ID and start the animation again. The animation started well, however, after few minutes the animation delay does not work or take more time instead of was set.

```js
setInterval(controlAninmation_A, 100);

function controlAninmation_A() {
  var getId = document.getElementById('AA');
  getId.setAttribute("id", "A");
  var removeId = document.getElementById('A'),
    setClass = removeId;
  setTimeout(changeClass, 20000);

  function changeClass() {
    var checkClass = setClass.getAttribute("class");

    if (checkClass != "change") {
      setClass.setAttribute("class", "change");
    }
  }

  clearTimeout(changeClass);
  setTimeout(changeId, 30000);

  function changeId() {
    removeId.setAttribute("id", "AA");
    console.log("The function was executed 100% ");
  }

  clearTimeout(changeId);
}

clearInterval(controlAninmation_A);
setInterval(controlAninmation_B, 4000);

function controlAninmation_B() {

  var getId = document.getElementById('BB');
  if (getId != "B") {
    getId.setAttribute("id", "B");
  }

  var removeId = document.getElementById('B'),
    setClass = removeId;
  setTimeout(changeClass, 34000);

  function changeClass() {
    var checkClass = setClass.getAttribute("class");

    if (checkClass != "change") {
      setClass.setAttribute("class", "change");
      console.log("changed class");
    }
  }

  clearTimeout(changeClass);
  setTimeout(changeId, 27000);

  function changeId() {
    removeId.setAttribute("id", "BB");
  }

  clearTimeout(changeId);
}

clearInterval(controlAninmation_B);
setInterval(controlAninmation_C, 11000);

function controlAninmation_C() {

  var getId = document.getElementById('CC');
  if (getId != "C") {
    getId.setAttribute("id", "C");
  }

  var removeId = document.getElementById('C'),
    setClass = removeId;
  setTimeout(changeClass, 20000);

  function changeClass() {
    var checkClass = setClass.getAttribute("class");

    if (checkClass != "change") {
      setClass.setAttribute("class", "change");
      console.log("changed class");
    }
  }

  clearTimeout(changeClass);
  setTimeout(changeId, 41000);

  function changeId() {
    removeId.setAttribute("id", "CC");
  }

  clearTimeout(changeId);

}

clearInterval(controlAninmation_C);
setInterval(controlAninmation_D, 17000);

function controlAninmation_D() {
  var getId = document.getElementById('DD');
  if (getId != "D") {
    getId.setAttribute("id", "D");
  }

  var removeId = document.getElementById('D'),
      setClass = removeId;
  setTimeout(changeClass, 20000);

  function changeClass() {
    var checkClass = setClass.getAttribute("class");
    if (checkClass != "change") {
      setClass.setAttribute("class", "change");
      console.log("changed class");
    }
  }

  clearTimeout(changeClass);
  setTimeout(changeId, 47000);

  function changeId() {
    removeId.setAttribute("id", "DD");
  }

  clearTimeout(changeId);

}

clearInterval(controlAninmation_D);
setInterval(controlAninmation_E, 20000);

function controlAninmation_E() {

  var getId = document.getElementById('EE');
  if (getId != "E") {
    getId.setAttribute("id", "E");
  }

  var removeId = document.getElementById('E'),
      setClass = removeId; setTimeout(changeClass, 20000);

  function changeClass() {
    var checkClass = setClass.getAttribute("class");

    if (checkClass != "change") {
      setClass.setAttribute("class", "change");
      console.log("changed class");
    }
  }

  clearTimeout(changeClass);
  setTimeout(changeId, 50000);

  function changeId() {
    removeId.setAttribute("id", "EE");
  } clearTimeout(changeId);
}

clearInterval(controlAninmation_E);
setInterval(controlAninmation_F, 24000);

function controlAninmation_F() {
  var getId = document.getElementById('FF');
  if (getId != "") {
    getId.setAttribute("id", "F");
  }

  var removeId = document.getElementById('F'),
      setClass = removeId; setTimeout(changeClass, 20000);

  function changeClass() {
    var checkClass = setClass.getAttribute("class");

    if (checkClass != "change") {
      setClass.setAttribute("class", "change");
      console.log("changed class");
    }
  }

  clearTimeout(changeClass);
  setTimeout(changeId, 54000);

  function changeId() {
    removeId.setAttribute("id", "FF");
  }
  clearTimeout(changeId);
}

clearInterval(controlAninmation_F);
setInterval(controlAninmation_G, 27000);

function controlAninmation_G() {
  var getId = document.getElementById('GG');
  if (getId != "") {
    getId.setAttribute("id", "G");
  }
  var removeId = document.getElementById('G'),
    setClass = removeId;
  setTimeout(changeClass, 20000);

  function changeClass() {
    var checkClass = setClass.getAttribute("class");
    if (checkClass != "change") {
      setClass.setAttribute("class", "change");
      console.log("changed class");
    }
  }

  clearTimeout(changeClass);
  setTimeout(changeId, 57000);

  function changeId() {
    removeId.setAttribute("id", "GG");
  }
  clearTimeout(changeId);
}

clearInterval(controlAninmation_G);
setInterval(controlAninmation_H, 30000);

    function controlAninmation_H() {

      var getId = document.getElementById('HH');
      if (getId != "") {
        getId.setAttribute("id", "H");
      } moveId = document.getElementById('H'),
        setClass = removeId;
      setTimeout(changeClass, 20000);

      function changeClass() {
        var checkClass = setClass.getAttribute("class");

        if (checkClass != "change") {
          setClass.setAttribute("class", "change");
          console.log("changed class");
        }
      }

      clearTimeout(changeClass);
      setTimeout(changeId, 60000);

      function changeId() {
        removeId.setAttribute("id", "HH");
      }
      clearTimeout(changeId);
}

clearInterval(controlAninmation_H);
```

```css
#A{ animation-name: wave;animation-duration: 20s;  animation-iteration-count: 1;animation-timing-function:linear;  }
    #B{ animation-name: QQQ;animation-duration: 20s;  animation-iteration-count: 1;animation-timing-function:linear;  }
    #C{ animation-name: EEEE;animation-duration: 20s; animation-iteration-count: 1; animation-timing-function:linear; }
    #D{ animation-name: RRRR;animation-duration: 20s;  animation-iteration-count: 1; animation-timing-function:linear; }
    #E{ animation-name: AAAA;animation-duration: 20s; animation-iteration-count: 1; animation-timing-function:linear; }
    #F{ animation-name: DDDDDD;animation-duration: 20s;  animation-iteration-count: 1;animation-timing-function:linear;  }
    #G{ animation-name:GGGGGGG;animation-duration: 20s; animation-iteration-count: 1; animation-timing-function:linear; }
    #H{ animation-name:KKKKKKKK;animation-duration: 20s; animation-iteration-count: 1;animation-timing-function:linear;  }
 
    .hidden{
    position: relative;
    top: 160px;}
    .change{
     position: relative;
    top: 160px;}
    @keyframes A{0%{transform: translateX(0%); top:17px; margin-left: 10px;margin-right: 10px;visibility: visible;  }100%{transform: translateX(100%); top:17px; margin-left: 10px;margin-right: 10px;visibility: visible; }}
    @keyframes B{0%{transform: translateX(0%);top:0px; margin-right: 10px;visibility: visible; }100%{transform: translateX(100%);top:0px; margin-right: 10px; visibility: visible; }}
    @keyframes C{0%{transform: translateX(0%);top:-17px;  margin-right: 10px;visibility: visible; }100%{transform: translateX(100%);top:-17px; margin-right: 10px;visibility: visible; }}
    @keyframes D{0%{transform: translateX(0%);top:-34px;margin-right: 10px;visibility: visible; }100%{transform: translateX(100%);top:-34px;margin-right: 10px;visibility: visible; }}
    @keyframes E{0%{transform: translateX(0%);top:-51px;margin-right: 10px;visibility: visible; }100%{transform: translateX(100%);top:-51px;margin-right: 10px;visibility: visible; }}
    @keyframes F{0%{transform: translateX(0%);top:-68px;margin-right: 10px;visibility: visible; }100%{transform: translateX(100%);top:-68px;margin-right: 10px;visibility: visible; }}
    @keyframes G{0%{transform: translateX(0%);top:-85px;margin-right: 10px;visibility: visible; }100%{transform: translateX(100%);top:-85px;margin-right: 10px;visibility: visible; }}
    @keyframes H{0%{transform: translateX(0%);top:-102px;margin-right: 10px;margin-left: 10px;visibility: visible; }100%{transform: translateX(100%);top:-102px;margin-right: 10px;margin-left: 10px;visibility: visible; }}
```

```html
<div id="AA" class="hidden"><a href="#">Welcome to StackOvervlow</a></div>
<div id="BB" class="hidden"><a href="#">Welcome to StackOvervlow</a></div>   
<div id="CC" class="hidden"><a href="#">Welcome to StackOvervlow</a></div>   
<div id="DD" class="hidden"><a href="#">Welcome to StackOvervlow</a></div>   
<div id="EE" class="hidden"><a href="#">Welcome to StackOvervlow</a></div>   
<div id="FF" class="hidden"><a href="#">Welcome to StackOvervlow</a></div>   
<div id="GG" class="hidden"><a href="#">Welcome to StackOvervlow</a></div>   
<div id="HH" class="hidden"><a href="#">Welcome to StackOvervlow</a></div>
```

Comment: Please helps us all and help yourself, give format to the javascript code to make it readable to all.

Comment: One of the best pieces of advice you'll ever get in learning to program is ["DRY"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (Don't Repeat Yourself). You've got function after function that are just about identical. None of that is needed. You can make just one function and pass it the values that change as arguments.

Comment: I wrote many function that have their own ID to manipulate it frequently.

Comment: when you call setInterval, it returns an id that you need to pass into clearInterval, you can't just pass in the function that you used in setinterval to clear it.

Comment: OK but how to correct my mistake?

Comment: How long did that take to write? One of the most fundamental reasons why programming is so important is because we write code so we don't repeat ourselves and we have our computers to do all of the repetitive tasks for us. Own the algorithm, don't let it own you.